# Plot two boxplots in one figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make one figure with two categories of data, which looks like:
[A comparison between two groups (indicated by pink and black) concerning various different species](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ISz5.jpg)

It seems the author of this figure put two boxplot pictures into one figure. I constructed similar boxplot by R, codes like below:

```
{library(reshape2)
species_melt <- melt(species, "Species")
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(species_melt, aes(Species, value),color="Red") + geom_boxplot()
windowsFonts(myFont1=windowsFont("Arial"),myFont2=windowsFont("Times New    Roman"))
p+scale_y_log10()}
```

Which generate a boxplot like below (partly):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCvqz.png)

Thus I wonder how I could add another layer of boxplot on it, yet it seems difficult with R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to test without having your data, but something like this should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(data = species_melt_1, 
                 aes(Species, value),
                 fill = "#ff84b3", color = "#994f6b") +
    geom_boxplot(data = species_melt_2, 
                 aes(Species, value),
                 alpha = 0, color = "black")
```

I'm using two `geom_boxplot`'s with different datasets (`species_melt_1` and `species_melt_2`). First one is reddish and second one is transparent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's just what I need. How do you add short lines to the max and min value in the boxplot? As in this case the max and min values might be overlapped.